# How to sort and return records with a given value in a given field last in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Foo.order( status: :on_hold ...?
```

How to order so that all `Foos` with a status of `on_hold` are returned last?

RoR 4. Postgres.

Comment: Try this `Foo.order( "status = 'on_hold' , status")`.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work :

```
Foo.order( "status = 'on_hold', status")
```

A quick test on Postgresql *Boolean* ordering :

```
app=# select * from test1;
 a |    b
---+---------
 t | sic est
 f | non est
(2 rows)

app=# select * from test1 order by a;
 a |    b
---+---------
 f | non est
 t | sic est
(2 rows)

app=#
```

Well as *@muistooshort* said, you can do :

```
Foo.order("CASE status WHEN 'on_hold' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, status")
```

Comment: Using a CASE might be a more portable approach than relying boolean ordering: `case status when 'on_hold' then 1 else 0 end, status`.

Comment: @muistooshort I like your thought, but `Postgresql` _boolean_ `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`.. [see](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-boolean.html).. That's why I used it.

Comment: PostgreSQL actually has a native boolean type that can be *input* using various *string* formats such as `'1'` and `'0'`. I don't think there is a specified ordering for booleans even though they will almost certain compare in the expected fashion.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks. I always used this kind of expression when I need special ordering. See one sample result I added

Comment: All I'm saying is that there is a difference between "it works in this test" and "it is guaranteed to work".

Comment: @muistooshort true. You are a clean developer.. :)

Comment: FWIW, `Foo.order("status = 'on_hold'")` was all that is necessary. Otherwise it will order on_hold foos last *and* sort by status.

Comment: @BSeven Thanks.. You have 2 options. Pick the one you like most. :)

Comment: @BSeven I didn't get what you said. At any cost, the both query will put 'on hold' last... and other statuses by their alphabetical sort...